# How to bind model id in AngularJs with select element of type (id, name)?

Tags: angularjs

I have a simple model : `$scope.user = {email: "", birth_month: 0}`

Binding user input to email is easy :

```
<input type="email" ... ng-model="user.email">
```

However I would like to have a `<select>` list showing months as "January", "February" etc but directly binding to `user.birth_month` as integer

I understand that I can do :

```
$scope.months = [{name: "January", value: 0}, {name: "February", value: 1} ...]
```

and

```
<select ng-model=monthObj ng-options="month as month.name for month in months>
</select>
```

In the scope I will then have a pointer to a month object {name, value} and on change I can set the `user.birth_month` but I feel like I am completely loosing the power of AngularJS here.

*Any more direct way* to bind `user.birth_month` with `month.value` ?

Comment: use `ng-options="month as month.name for month in months track by month.name"`

Comment: @pankajparkar didn't know about track by but they say in the doc they don't work together https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions

Answer (score 0):

You can simple use ng-init like this

```
<select ng-init="monthObj = months[user.birth_month]" ng-model="monthObj" ng-options="month as month.name for month in months"></select>
```

Comment: what to put in ng-init="", give answer with proper solution

Comment: <select ng-init="monthObj = months[user.birth_month]" ng-model="monthObj" ng-options="month as month.name for month in months"></select>

Comment: @AramGrig yes, let me try

Comment: @AramGrig ng-init is a good thing but how do you bind it to `user.birth_month` ?

Comment: if so 
<select  ng-model="user.birth_month" ng-options="month as month.name for month in months"></select>

Comment: Please sorry  that I have not help you